# Does reactive database return all data at once?

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, spring-webflux

my question is pretty straightforward, when we make asynchronous call with reactive repository from Spring, do we:

Receive all data from database (MongoDB) at once and put it into reactive type Flux?

Or

Receive data in chunks at rate that Driver is reading them from database?

My confusion here is that if database Driver is working as traditional one or is it working on Producer/Subscriber pattern that we use inside our SpringFlux application.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

An R2DBC compliant driver is a non blocking driver that will stream items if returned as a flux.